# Ошибка при переходе на Swift 4 - Expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Перехожу на Swift 4, выдает ошибку "Expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time; consider breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions"

```
let value =
      Int(topLeft.hashValue) |
      Int(topRight.hashValue) << 1 |
      Int(bottomLeft.hashValue) << 2 |
      Int(bottomRight.hashValue) << 3
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Помогло

```
var value = topLeft.hashValue
value = value | topRight.hashValue << 1
value = value | bottomLeft.hashValue << 2
value = value | bottomRight.hashValue << 3
```